# Writing JPQL query in Spring boot with ':' as a part of the query string

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

I have to write a JPQL query in spring boot which is equivalent to the below query.

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT * FROM flow.logs where feature_id like '%|data:6789%';
```

**JPQL Query made by me:**

```
@Query("SELECT logs FROM Logs logs WHERE logs.featureId like '%|data\\: :data%'")
    public List<Logs> getLogsByStationId(@Param("data")Integer data);
```

**The query is not working and giving the below exception:**
`Unknown parameter position: 1; nested exception is` `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You also can use @Query(value="normal sql query",nativeQuery=true) to avoid that

Comment: @Frank : This is not working.

Comment: Are you using spring data jpa? If you are, take a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Try the following: 
`@Query("SELECT logs FROM Logs logs WHERE logs.featureId like '%|data\\: ?1%'")
    public List<Logs> getLogsByStationId(Integer data);`

Comment: You can get rid of the `@Query` by using the naming convention of spring JPA repository: `public List<Logs> getLogsByStationIdContaining(Integer data);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **CONCAT** function like this :

```
@Query("SELECT logs FROM Logs logs WHERE "
        + "logs.featureId like CONCAT('%|data:', :data, '%')")
```